# Return city and state from string

Tags: php, regex

I have an API call returning a field meetingAddress with the following format.
Street "" City "," State ZipCode.  The "" in this example is to show where the matching characters fall into the string.

I have fiddled around with substr and strpos but due to my limit experience cannot seem to get it to work. I am writing a function to take the address and return just the city and state.

```
$str needs to be populated with the MeetingAddress data
$from = "#xD;";  - this is always before the city
$to = ","; - this is after the city
echo getStringBetween($str,$from,$to);
function getStringBetween($str,$from,$to)
{
$sub = substr($str, strpos($str,$from)+strlen($from),strlen($str));
return substr($sub,0,strpos($sub,$to));
}
```

Here is an exact example of what is being returned.

```
      <d:MeetingAddress>44045 Five Mile Rd&#xD;
      Plymouth, MI 48170-2555</d:MeetingAddress>
```

Here is a second example:

```
      <d:MeetingAddress>PO Box 15526&#xD;
      Houston, TX 77220-5526</d:MeetingAddress>
```

Comment: Post an exact example of the string returned from the API.

Comment: Where is the string? provide a example of a response you getting..

Comment: I appended the response to the question. Thank you!

Comment: And what exactly do you want to get from those strings?

Comment: Your code seems to be doing what it is supposed to, albeit not what you want. You call `getStringBetween($str, "#xD;", ",")` and that does exactly what it sounds like it does. It gets the city. Why would you expect it to get the state too?

Comment: I don't, I am tinkering trying to get the code to give me both the city and state in the cleanest most efficient way possible. Still learning.

Comment: Also, the output of the code above is not returning the city only.

Comment: do you need state with ZIP or only state?

Comment: I only need the state.  City, State

Comment: @Shafizadeh, he wants "Houston, TX".

Comment: @Chris Tnx for the tip .. but there is several answer under his question and I think they are enough `;-)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like below

```
$string = '44045 Five Mile Rd&#xD;Plymouth, MI 48170-2555';

list($address,$cityAndState) = explode('#xD;',$string);
list($city,$state) = explode(',',$cityAndState);
echo $address;
echo $city;
echo $state;
```

Comment: That code is so beautiful it makes me get a little teary eyed! :D  Thank you @vishnu!

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "<d:MeetingAddress>44045 Five Mile Rd&#xD;Plymouth, MI 48170-2555</d:MeetingAddress>";
preg_match('/&#xD;(.*),(.*) /', $str, $matches);
```

`$matches[1]` is the city, `$matches[2]` is the state

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `explode()` function:

```
$str = '<d:MeetingAddress>44045 Five Mile Rd&#xD;Plymouth, MI 48170-2555</d:MeetingAddress>';
$tmp = explode(';', $str);
$details = explode(',',$tmp[1]);
$details[1] = substr(trim($details[1]),0,2);
var_dump($details);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Plymouth
    [1] => MI
)
```